# Batch File to Check File Opened by Program

Tags: batch-file

I would like to use tasklist to detect a specific Access project file that has been opened. Although I can see the file opened in Task Manager, I can not figure out to check for that file using a tasklist batch command. Any help?

Comment: so you want to check if a certain file is being hold by a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a known string in the Window Title, *like perhaps the file name*, you should be able to filter `TaskList` with your known `ImageName`, *(`MSACCESS.EXE`)*, the `/V`erbose option and pipe the output to `find.exe`. If you do that within a `For /F` loop, you should be able to `TaskKill` it in the `Do` portion.

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=2Delims=," %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%tasklist.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq MSACCESS.EXE" /V /Fo CSV^|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /I "MyFile.accdb" 2^>NUL^"')Do @"%__AppDir__%taskkill.exe" /PID %%~G
```

*Obviously you'd change `"MyFile.accdb"` to your known file name.*

**[Edit /]**

Here's an example, *(without `TaskKill`)*, to just determine if the file is open in Access.

```batch-file
@("%__AppDir__%tasklist.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq MSACCESS.EXE" /V /Fo CSV 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /I "MyFile.accdb">NUL&&(Echo File is open.)||Echo File is not open.)&Pause
```

Comment: I do not wish to kill the task, so I have tried this with  'DO @echo goto found' (no quotes). However, it is either not recognizing the  file (SBGOLFII.ACCDR and sbgolfii.accdr) or not recognizing the goto command. Ant ideas?

Comment: If you don't wish to kill it, and you simply want to know if the specific file is open in access, you can remove the `for-loop` and just use `find`. I've added an example to the answer area above. Please don't forget, if my answer helps solve your issue, that marking it as accepted will help the site and future readers/visitors.

Comment: Aha! I just realized I should not have included @echo in the do command. Now works fine - thanks...